# Как обратиться к предыдущему элементу?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть слайдер у которого есть центральный слайд с классом "active". Центральный слайд меняется при переключении слайдера. Как обратиться (задать стили) предыдущему классу "active" элементу? (помечен)

```
  <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div> (к этому)
      <div class="slide active"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `elem.previousElementSibling`

Comment: Это довольно сложно реализовать, так как слайдер может прокручиваться в обе стороны. Тогда нужно ловить еще и nextElementSibling.

Comment: Ну тогда делайте, кто-то вас останавливает?

Comment: Есть ли еще способы?

Comment: индекс текущего слайдера минус 1 (и плюс соответственно для следующего), сохраняете и обращаетесь к `children` у `.slider` и выбираете нужный вам слайд.

Comment: Это то, что нужно. Благодарю!